# Installing mjpg-streamer

Tags: opencv

I tried to install mjpg-streamer(experimental) in pi. But I don't know what to do after the following command. This remains a lot of time. If I tried to kill it shows errors for next command.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental $ ./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www"
MJPG Streamer Version: svn rev: 
 o: www-folder-path...: ./www/
 o: HTTP TCP port.....: 8080
 o: username:password.: disabled
 o: commands..........: enabled
```

What can I do next?

Comment: Wohoo! Welldone

Comment: How did you successfully build it? I always run into a Segmentation fault when I run make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those messages are good news, it means it is working and waiting for a connection on port 8080. Use your browser on any other machine, go to the IP address op the Raspberry Pi like this:

```
http://<ip-address-of-pi>:8080
```

and you should be presented with a page where you can switch to streaming video, or snapshots.

Comment: Hi, it is not working. I got message from vlc media player as :-Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://192.168.1.30:8080/?action=stream'.

Comment: Yes,mjpg-streamer is working with another camera.Logitech hd720p and shows bad images for e-con ecam -32 web cam.Ref: http://www.tanzilli.com/video_streaming

Comment: Thank you,it is working with econ ecam 32 .I just replaced its votage regulator,with Ti's pjrq 3.3 voltage regulator. Thank you very much for your support